# Making table elements (from JSON) linkable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I have a JSON file that contains document titles and a URL for each. So far I've been able to render each document into a table created with `DataTables.` I also rendered each url into the first table row as a test. It was good that they appeared but it's not what I'm going for.

How can I make it so that each document title is linked with its respective URL? I didn't see any info. about it in the DataTables manual or its forum so I thought I'd ask.

If you'd like to see a snippet of the JSON file, please let me know.

#### JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import JSONfile from '../../../public/JSONfile.json';
import { basename } from 'path';

import dt from 'datatables.net';

var tableRes = '';

    export default class {
        constructor() {
            this.loadTableData();
        }

 loadTableData() {
    $.noConflict();
    let tableRes = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) {
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {

      return {
        // "FileName": obj.FileLeafRef,
        // "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl, ///// these are the URLs for each document
        "Titles": obj.File.Name
        }
      });

    $('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        { "data": "&nbsp;" },
        { "data": "Titles" }, ///// Ideally I want each Title to be linked in the table---i.e. the document names appearing blue
        { "data": "&nbsp;" }
      ],
      data: tableRes,
      "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    });

 } // ------- loadTableData

} // ------- export default class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:* Thanks to a user on the DataTables forum, I was able to find a solution. Simply put, I had to use `columDefs` that was detailed under the `columns.render` [section of the docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) :

#### Code snippet:

```
      return {
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name
        }
      });

    $('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        { data: "Path" }, // populates rows with each document link
        { data: "Titles" }, // populates rows with docs
        { data: "check" }
      ],
      columnDefs: [ {
        targets: 0,
        data: "Path",
        render: function(data) {
          return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
        }
      }],
...
```

#### Hyperlinking actual document cells:

```
 columnDefs: [
        {
          data: "Path",
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            return $('<a>')
              .attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
              .text(data)
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
          },
          targets: [] // Column position
        },
...
```